# Next lexicographically bigger permutation of a string

Tags: java, algorithm

Question is to find lexicographical next bigger string than the given string 
 for ex: Input: DKHC  OP: HKDC.

I am not able to figure out where i am doing wrong in my code. Can someone help me to debug.

*

```
public static void main(String[] main)
    {
        String s = "gojh";
        String op="";
        //System.out.println();
        int i=s.length()-1;
        int j=i-1;
        boolean swapped=false;
        while(i>0)
        {
            j=i-1;
        while(j>=0)
        {   if(s.charAt(i)>s.charAt(j))
            {   System.out.println(s.charAt(j)+" ->"+s.charAt(i));
                s=s.substring(0,j)+s.charAt(i)+s.substring(j+1,i)+s.charAt(j)+s.substring(i+1);
                swapped=true;
                break;
            }
            else 
            {
                j--;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(i);
        if(swapped)
            break;
        else
            i--;

      } 
        //System.out.println(s);
        if((i-j)>=2)
           op= minimize(s,j);
        else
            op=s;
        System.out.println(op);
    }
    private static String minimize(String s,int index) {
        String reverse="";
        String original=s.substring(index+1);
        int i=original.length()-1;
        while(i>=0)
        {
            reverse=reverse+original.charAt(i);
            i--;
        }
        //System.out.println(reverse);

        return s.substring(0,index+1)+reverse;
    }
```

*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no I/O examples that you have given in your code (input/output of code and expected output), so it is too exhaustive to debug it. But a glance at it tells me a couple of things:

1. You are actually using O(n^2) algo, (n = length of string), while this is easily solvable in one iteration.
2. Your example and problem description is wrong. If i/p is `DKHC`, next lexicographical bigger string would be `HCDK` and **not** `HKDC`.

So, assuming you did a mistake there, I'm giving you an algo to do the correct thing (according to problem description).

- Start from end of string towards the beginning. Find the index where `charAt(i) < charAt(i+1)`. Stop there.
  (If you don't get this condition and reach till the beginning of string, given i/p is already biggest lexical permutation that you can get. You can display an error message there)
- Now reiterate from the end, and find an index `j` such that `charAt(i) < charAt(j)`. You **will** surely find such index.
- Swap characters at indices `i` and `j`.
- Now the last *(and important)* step. Reverse the whole string from index `i+1` onward.

Comment: I believe you have a small error in your algorithm. I should be `charAt(i) < charAt(j)` and not `charAt(i) > charAt(j)`.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the answer. Yes, it should have been `charAt(i) < charAt(j)`. And it *will* work if characters occur more than once.